# Updating Date inside a while loop, Java

Tags: java, loops, class, date, while-loop

Im trying to compare the real world date with a user input date within a while loop. Although the initial execute is correct, the second time its executing the date stays the same. Ive tried asking for the date inside the while loop and now most recently from within a class method but still the date stays the same.

How can I retrieve an up to date date?

```
import java.util.Date;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Watch {
    Date CurrentTimeAndDate = new Date();

    int CurrentMinutes() {
        int currentMinutes = CurrentTimeAndDate.getMinutes();
        System.out.println(currentMinutes);
        return currentMinutes;
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String timer = null;
        int i = 0;
        int num = 0;
        Date TimeAndDate = new Date();
        int getDay = TimeAndDate.getDay();
        int getMonth = TimeAndDate.getMonth() + 1;
        int getYear = TimeAndDate.getYear() + 1900;
        int getMinutes = TimeAndDate.getMinutes();
        Watch watch1 = new Watch();

        String[] Month = { "", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
        String[] Day = { "", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
        System.out.println("Current time and date is    " + TimeAndDate);
        System.out.println("Printing my way! " + Day[getDay] + " " + Month[getMonth] + " " + getYear + " " + getMinutes);
        System.out.println(" Enter a short description of what you want reminding about ");
        String rem = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" Enter date of reminder 1-7");
        while (i < 7) {
            System.out.println(i + 1 + " = " + Day[i + 1]);
            i++;
        }
        int day = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Month of reminder");
        i = 0;
        while (i < 12) {
            System.out.println(i + 1 + " " + "=" + " " + Month[i + 1]);
            i++;
        }
        int month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter year");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Minutes, for testing purposes");
        int userInputMinutes = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Date set to remind you about " + rem + " " + Day[day] + " " + Month[month] + " " + year);
        if (year > getYear) {
            System.out.println("Its time to remind you about ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Waiting");
        }
        int Mins = 0;
        while (userInputMinutes != Mins) {
            Mins = watch1.CurrentMinutes();
            System.out.println("Current Minutes = " + getMinutes);
            System.out.println("Entered minutes =" + userInputMinutes);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        System.out.println("Its time to remind you about " + rem);
    }
    public static void Date(String time) {
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You may also look into `DateTimeFormatter`. Even if you insisted on using `Date`, you should certainly stay far away from its `getYear`, `getMonth`, `getDay` and `getMinutes` methods, They were deprecated 20 years ago (literally) because they work unreliably across time zones.

Comment: Please, the Java naming conventions say that names of methods and variables should begin with a small letter, for example `currentMinutes` and `month`. While in your own code you can of course do as you please, at least when posting code on Stack Overflow, follow the convention. Some of us get disturbed when trying to read through code that doesn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the new Date() only once. So you will be getting that same in while loop iterations. To get a new date for every iteration, you have to set the below code inside the while loop

```
TimeAndDate = new Date();
int getDay = TimeAndDate.getDay();
int getMonth = TimeAndDate.getMonth() + 1;
int getYear = TimeAndDate.getYear() + 1900;
int getMinutes = TimeAndDate.getMinutes();
Watch watch1 = new Watch();
```

*** Note: Date is a deprecated class. Please refer @Ole V.V. answer for
 the correct class to use.***

Comment: I moved the above code into my Watch class and called on it from within the  while loop, which worked.

Comment: In my most honest opinion you are doing the questioner and the community a disfavour by helping anyone how to use the methods of the `Date` class that have been deprecated for decades including `getDay`, `getMonth`, `getYear` and `getMinutes`.

Comment: @OleV.V.  The scope of this question is not about which Class to use, but where to put his code when using the loop. Anyway, I updated the answer to point out that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First, use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for you date and time work. Always. The `Date` class that you used (misused, really, I’ll get back to that) is poorly designed and long outdated. Never use that.

### Getting current minutes

To get the current minute of the hour:

```
int currentMinutes() {
    return LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute();
}
```

### To read day of week or month from the user

Also use java.time for days of the week and for months. Your code is reinventing wheels. You should prefer to use library classes and methods that are already there for you. For example:

```
    System.out.println(" Enter day of week of reminder 1-7");
    for (DayOfWeek dow : DayOfWeek.values()) {
        System.out.println("" + dow.getValue() + " = " + dow
                .getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
    int day = input.nextInt();
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.of(day);
    System.out.println("You have chosen " + dow);
```

Example interaction:

> ```
>  Enter day of week of reminder 1-7
> 1 = Mon
> 2 = Tue
> 3 = Wed
> 4 = Thu
> 5 = Fri
> 6 = Sat
> 7 = Sun
> 2
> You have chosen TUESDAY
> ```

### Most methods of the Date class are deprecated for a reason

As I said, `Date` is poorly designed and long outdated. More than that, most of the constructors and methods of the class were deprecated in Java 1.1 in February 1997 because they work unreliably across time zones. So even if you insisted on using `Date` (which I hope you don’t), you should still stay far away from the deprecated methods including all of the `get` methods except `getTime` (which converts to milliseconds since the epoch).

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.